# How to use my java class in kivy app using kivy launcher

Tags: java, android, python

I'm trying to write a simple kivy application for android using kivy launcher. I'm trying to use pyjnius to call java functions from my java class. I put the java class in the same folder as the python file in the kivy launcher directory. When I test the application on windows it works but on android I get the "class not found" exception.

Is it possible to use java class in launcher directory or I have to build kivy with my class included?

On windows the class was compiled with jdk1.8.0_73 and on android it was compiled with android studio.

here is the python code:

```
import os
appPath = os.path.abspath(".")
classPath = appPath + "/znt/tageja/ardbt/MainActivity"     

import jnius_config
#jnius_config.set_classpath(appPath)     # appPath: not working
jnius_config.set_classpath(classPath)   # classPath: not working

# This is not working also:
#os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = appPath

from jnius import autoclass
mtcClass = autoclass("znt.tageja.ardbt.MainActivity")

s = mtcClass()
print s
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the class path for jnius is not suported on android, see [here](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jvm-options-and-the-class-path)

Therefore, the java class for android needs to be compiled in the python-for-android distribution as shown in [this](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/android.html#accelerometer-access) example.